# Can Java determine if there are global/OS keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way for Java to figure out if there are globally accessible shortcuts defined outside of a java desktop application?

The purpose is for a keyboard shortcut configuration UI, we might warn the user that they are overriding OS shortcuts and might want to choose a different keystroke.

Comment: What operating systems are you targeting?

Comment: I'm not sure how this could be done in any language... If you can find a resource answering your question for a natively compiled language such as c++ then you may be able to adapt the same concept using a library like JNA. This is assuming you're targeting windows, of course. If you're trying to remain multi-platform (as you should when using Java) then you may just be out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that won't be possible due to:

- Too many different operating systems or desktop environments (as it is the case with Linux)
- Not reachable since they are not stored in plain text

I think your best shot is to define them all (or at least the very important ones). After all the list of short cuts are available. I also found [Table of keyboard shortcuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) since they give an overview of the shortcuts over different operating systems.

For GNOME I found the following question: [Where are GNOME keyboard shortcuts stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26056/where-are-gnome-keyboard-shortcuts-stored)

> Depending on your distro version, the keyboard shortcuts application
>   may be called different things in the GUI but on the command line it
>   should be called 'gnome-keybinding-properties'. It turns out that this
>   neat little application brings all of the shortcuts into one
>   convenient place for users to edit.

Besides, defining shortcuts for your application won't **override** the operating system shortcuts, they are just not functional in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that this is possible, there maybe some things that can be done to run native commands using the [RunTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html), class.  But executing native os level commands through Java is not usually a good idea.

However, it is probably worth showing list of commonly used shortcuts warning your users that these may not be available depending on their OS. You could however, add a quick test warning them if they were overriding one that is commonly used.